# average bins along a dimension of a nd array in matlab

Tags: matlab

To compute the mean of every bins along a dimension of a nd array in matlab, for example, average every 10 elements along dim 4 of a 4d array

```
x = reshape(1:30*30*20*300,30,30,20,300);    
n = 10; 
m = size(x,4)/10;
y = nan(30,30,20,m);
for ii = 1 : m
    y(:,:,:,ii) = mean(x(:,:,:,(1:n)+(ii-1)*n),4);
end
```

It looks a bit silly. I think there must be better ways to average the bins?

Besides, is it possible to make the script applicable to general cases, namely, arbitray ndims of array and along an arbitray dim to average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question you can use this:

```
x = reshape(1:30*30*20*300,30,30,20,300);    
dim = 4;
n = 10; 
m = size(x,dim)/10;
y = nan(30,30,20,m);
idx1 = repmat({':'},1,ndims(x));
idx2 = repmat({':'},1,ndims(x));
for ii = 1 : m
    idx1{dim} = ii;
    idx2{dim} = (1:n)+(ii-1)*n;
    y(idx1{:}) = mean(x(idx2{:}),dim);
end
```

For the first part of the question here is an alternative using `cumsum` and `diff`, but it may not be better then the loop solution:

```
function y = slicedmean(x,slice_size,dim)
    s = cumsum(x,dim);
    idx1 = repmat({':'},1,ndims(x));
    idx2 = repmat({':'},1,ndims(x));
    idx1{dim} = slice_size;
    idx2{dim} = slice_size:slice_size:size(x,dim);
    y = cat(dim,s(idx1{:}),diff(s(idx2{:}),[],dim))/slice_size;
end
```

Comment: BTW Octave has the function [accumdim](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/accumdim.html) that is useful for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution, using the `accumarray` function. I haven't tested how fast it is. There might be some room for improvement though.

Basically, accumarray groups the value in x following a matrix of customized index for your question

```
x = reshape(1:30*30*20*300,30,30,20,300); 
s = size(x);

% parameters for averaging
dimAv = 4; 
n = 10;

% get linear index
ix = (1:numel(x))';

% transform them to a matrix of index per dimension
% this is a customized version of ind2sub
pcum = [1 cumprod(s(1:end-1))];
sub = zeros(numel(ix),numel(s));
for i = numel(s):-1:1,
    ixtmp = rem(ix-1, pcum(i)) + 1;
    sub(:,i) = (ix - ixtmp)/pcum(i) + 1;
    ix = ixtmp;
end

% correct index for the given dimension
sub(:,dimAv) = floor((sub(:,dimAv)-1)/n)+1;

% run the accumarray to compute the average
sout = s;
sout(dimAv) = ceil(sout(dimAv)/n);
y = accumarray(sub,x(:), sout, @mean);
```

If you need a faster and memory efficient operation, you'll have to write your own mex function. It shouldn't be so difficult, I think !

Comment: what's `s`? it's not defined. And it looks in this method `dimAv` has to be the last dim?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. `s` is the size of your array! `dimAv` can be anything. `n` should be chosen accordin to the number of elements in the x at the dimAv dimension.

Comment: Just corrected the output size, which was not working all the time.